# Delphi - How trigger a Windows Message from a Form and retrieve it in a component that is in that Form using Delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi, postmessage

How trigger a Windows Message from a Form and retrieve it in a component that is in that Form using Delphi?

Ex:

In Form:

```
PostMessage(Handle, MY_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

In my Component (that is in same Form):

```
procedure OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message MY_MESSAGE;
```

in my case, OnMyMessage is simply not called!

**The message is not only for this component, it is public, present on Form even if the component is not present. Thank you!**

Comment: Presumably it's your component?  Change Handle in PostMessage to call your components Handle property.  You're calling the Form's Handle property

Comment: Yes, but the message is not only for this component, it is public, present on Form even if the component is not present. Thank you!

Comment: You will need to add the OnMyMessage to your form then, not the component.  If you want your message to go to multiple components (controls) you'll need to look into broadcast messages

Comment: Despite from the wrong handle, what's the ancestor of your component, does it have a handle?

Comment: The component could hook the parent's window procedure, see e.g. [WindowProc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.WindowProc).

Comment: Sometimes it helps to not only say what you are trying to do, but why you are trying to do it. Sometimes there's a better way. Sometimes it helps with people being able to write sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the form, `Handle` is the window handle of the form. If you wish for the component to be the recipient then you need to use the component's window handle, if it has one:

```
PostMessage(MyComponent.Handle, MY_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

Now, you also say:

> The message is not only for this component, it is public, present on Form even if the component is not present.

If that means that you want the form to receive the message as well as the component you are out of luck. Messages have a single recipient. You may need to post to the form, handle the message in the form and then delegate to any other components that need to be notified.